# Need to take variable input from text box to create a link to use with USPS Tracking System

Tags: javascript, java, html

This is a silly question but I can't seem to find an example that works. Basically I want to add a section on my website for the customer to check their USPS Tracking Number Status; USPS only provides an XML API while I need HTML / JS for this to work.

I need to create a text box that takes a 22 character (or less) alphanumeric variable so that when you click a "Submit" button, it will put the variable into this link.

Sadly, I need the entire script code from the  and  tags. I have tried every example I found and none of them worked in the sandbox, likely because I am missing some basic tags. I have come to the conclusion that I have no clue what I'm doing so please do not get frustrated by the simplicity of my question.

https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?strOrigTrackNum={xxx}  where xxx is must be the variable. Every example of code I have found will append to a link, but not put the variable inside the {}. I have been looking and tried a ton of different examples, but being far from a codemonkey I could really use some help. I apologize in advance because I know this is simple but I don't know what I am doing wrong except for trying to do something I have no business trying to do as I'm not a developer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to write the code yourself before posting. If you have a *specific* coding question, it should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here is the last thing i tried and doesn't work

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToPage() {
        var page = document.getElementById('trackingNumber').value;
        window.location = "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?strOrigTrackNum=" + trackingNumber;
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="trackingNumber" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Please add any additional information to the question itself using the "edit" link. Information in comments may be missed. I'd also suggest simplifying your question to include just the relevant details.

Comment: I GOT IT! :)  Ok, I got it to work using this.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToPage() {
        var page = document.getElementById('USPS_Tracking_Number').value;
        window.location = "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?strOrigTrackNum=" + page;
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="USPS_Tracking_Number" />
<input type="submit" value="Check USPS Tracking Number" onclick="goToPage();" /><input type="reset" value="Reset">

</body>
</html>

Comment: When you tag your question be sure you are using the correct tag. Your question is not related to Xcode

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, Sorry about that, I never intended that to be under Xcode, I must have selected that by mistake as it was supposed to be under javascript. I don't even know what Xcode is and this was my first time posting here, and I was having some difficultly understanding how to post a question properly.  Is there a way to remove the XCode tag? I have 2 final questions for this question I need help with but I think I will open a new question and try to clean up this mess of a question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the answer to my own question here us the correct code,

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goToPage() {
    var page = document.getElementById('USPS_Tracking_Number').value;
    window.location = "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?>strOrigTrackNum=" + page;
  }
</script>
```